# Create a simple sftp server for use with Mule

Tags: mule, sftp, anypoint-studio

I am looking to setup a local mock SFTP server to use with Mule.

I have a SFTP endpoint and would like to process files from c:/temp/file directory on my local machine.

I have looked at MUnit but would like to run my Mule project like I would in Production and I feel MUnit is more geared towards Unit Testing.

I have looked at FreeSSH and OpenSSH but due to privileges on my laptop I have been unable to install them because they run scripts.  I have also looked at CrushFTP but have had problems connecting to the sftp server.

Could anyone recommend a simple SFTP server I could setup locally to work with the Mule connector?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used solarwinds SFTP server to explore mule sftp connector.
 http://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/free-sftp-server/

Answer (score 0):

I made [sham-ssh](https://github.com/shamsoftware/sham-ssh#example-usage) which contains an in-process SFTP server that I use for production-like functional testing.  It allows you to use SSH or SFTP over a localhost network connection, and uses a directory on your hard drive to store the files.  It's not 1.0 yet, and has no documentation yet, but might work for you.